# The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first-- getting this error when adding buttons dynamically

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an app where I am dynamically adding buttons for the number of friends that are in a list.  I can add 1 friend and view the Friend List fine.  But when I add a second friend and try to view the FriendList I get this error--

> The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView()
>   on the child's parent first

**here is my code**--

```
public class FriendsList extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {    

    @SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_friends_list);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        createButtons();    
    }

    private void createButtons() {
        int size = FriendSearch.allFriends.size();
        for (int i = 0; i <= size - 1; i++) {
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_friends_list);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            Button btn = new Button(this);

            for (int j = 0; j <= size - 1; j++) {
                String name = FriendSearch.allFriends.get(j).getUserName();
                btn.setText(name);

                btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //goes to this friend's profile page
                        FriendSearch.setIsFriend(true);
                        startActivity(new Intent(FriendsList.this, Profile.class));
                    }
                });
                layout.addView(btn);
            }    
        }
    }   

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_friends_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.addFriendOption:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, FriendSearch.class));
                break;

            case R.id.myProfileOption:
                FriendSearch.setIsFriend(false);
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Profile.class));
                break;

            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, getIntent());
                return true;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {    
    }
}
```

I think it wants me to clear the view when the page is called again so all the buttons can be added.  But in every way I have tried I get errors or a blank activity.

Answer (score 1):

Either move:

```
Button btn = new Button(this);
```

to be *inside* your `for (int j = 0; j <= size - 1; j++)` loop, or move:

```
layout.addView(btn);
```

to be *outside* your `for (int j = 0; j <= size - 1; j++)` loop.

As it stands right now, you are attempting to add the same `Button` several times, once for each pass of the `for (int j = 0; j <= size - 1; j++)` loop.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the crashing problem.  I did the first suggestion and it gave me 2 buttons for each- user1 user2 user1 user2.  and they they all go to user2 profile.  the 2nd suggestion gave me the proper number of buttons but they were for the same user.

Comment: But I think that has to do with other parts of my code.